# How to show content without excerpt?

Tags: posts

Post contains: `excerpt`, `read more`, `content`.
When browsing category page we see post's `excerpt` with `read more` link.
When clicking `read more` we see post's `excerpt` + `content`.

How to avoid showing excerpt (everything before read more link) on post's page?

Comment: have you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content and considered the use of the `$stripteaser` parameter?

Comment: @Michael, thank you so much! Exactly what I meant! Please post an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Codex Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content), you can set the argument $stripteaser to true in order to not show the excerpt:

```
the_content( null, true );
```